Economic trade-offs of rooftop solar
It’s a well known problem that rooftop solar drives up electricity prices for non-rooftop solar consumers. This has resulted in some advocates favoring utility scale solar.
Just today the Washington Post had a piece out highlighting this and comments from Professor Jesse Jenkins.
Naively, if you think about supply and demand curves, rooftop solar shifts the demand curve to the left, lowering the market equilibrium price. However, this does not occur here because utilities are a monopoly, right?
How does one avoid this potential trade off of higher electricity prices for everyone else if residential solar were to be further deployed?
Relatedly but on different scales, how could one avoid this trade-off in the case of a very rapid (say 4-8 years with federal governemnt involvement on this scale) build out of rooftop solar to maximum potential in the United States a la Joshi et al. 2021?

Did you read the full paper? The abstract says that the author proposes an alternative pricing model that works better for this issue.
